# MATLAB plot the solution for the Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: matlab, plot, traveling-salesman

I have a few points in space:

```
A  0 0
B  0 1
C  0 2
D  0 4
E  1 2
F  1 3
G  2 0
H  2 4
I  3 4
J  4 4
K  5 0
L  6 1
M  7 2
N  7 4
O  4 2
P  8 3
Q  8 4 ;
```

I also have a solution for the Traveling Salesman Problem, essentially the edges which have to be connected.

```
A B   1
A G   1
B C   1
C E   1
D F   1
D H   1
E F   1
G O   1
H I   1
I J   1
J N   1
K L   1
K O   1
L M   1
M P   1
N Q   1
P Q   1
```

I could plot the nodes but I am not sure how to specify the edges.

[image]

Comment: How are you storing your data?
What are the coordinates data structure and the TSP result one?
Depending on how you save this information you can recall the coordinate of the start/end point to draw a segment.

Comment: @roadRunner just plain text files

Comment: @roadrunner but in matlab, they exist as simple arrays or cell arrays

Comment: Is every letter in its own cell?

Could you add to your description a screenshot of your data structure?

Comment: MATLAB has a `graph` object type, which can be `plot`ted. See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graph-and-network-algorithms.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MATLOG toolbox from Dr. Michael Kay (NC State). Free download from [link](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/) ([backup link](https://mgkay.github.io/matlog/)).

Take a look at the `pplot()` documentation [(link here)](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/MatlogRef.htm#pplot). Specifically you can plot given the **Arc List**, denoted `IJ` in the documentation (see code below).

```
  % Examples:
  XY = [2 2; 3 1; 4 3; 1 4];                  % Points
  pplot(XY,'r.')
  pplot(XY,num2cell(1:4))
 
  IJ = [1 2; 1 3; 1 4];                       % Arc List
  h1 = pplot(IJ,XY,'g-');
  IJlab = {'(1,2)','(1,3)','(1,4)'};
  h2 = pplot(IJ,IJlab,XY);
  delete([h1; h2])
 
  loc = {[1 4 3 2 1]};                        % Loc Seq Vector
  h3 = pplot(loc,XY,'g-');
  loclab = {'(1,4)','(4,3)','(3,2)','(2,1)'};
  h4 = pplot(loc,loclab,XY);
  set(h3,'color','b')
```

This was able to quickly produce your desired plot.
[image: TSP Plot using OP data]

**Update**
Example using `tspnneighbor()` and `tsp2opt()` from the MATLOG [function list & documentation](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/MatlogRef.htm).

This approach uses a *location* vector which is just the node indices in sequence, e.g. `loc = [3 5 6 1 2 4 3]`.

```
% Add MATLOG directory to path
path(path,'C:\Users\username\mypathtoMATLOG')

% DATA
XY_NCcity = uscity('XY',strcmp('NC',uscity('ST'))); % Get NC city [lon, lat] coordinates
C = dists(XY_NCcity,XY_NCcity,'mi');  % Get distance matrix

% ANIMATION
% Closest Unvisited City Algorithm (Nearest Neighbor)
makemap(XY_NCcity)
h = pplot(XY_NCcity,'r.')
[loc,TC,bestvtx] = tspnneighbor(C,527,h)  % Start CUCA from node 527 (Raleigh)
```

Below is the output using cities in North Carolina. Further examination of the `tspnneighbor( )` function shows it uses MATLOG's `pplot` function.
[image: North Carolina TSP]

For completeness, there is also a two-opt improvement feature, `tsp2opt()`, which can improve the solution.

```
% OPTIONAL: ANIMATED TWO-OPT IMPROVEMENT
% Demonstrates what a "more optimal" tour would look like
% Final result is not guaranteed to be optimal
[loc,TC] = tsp2opt(loc,C,[],[],[],h); % Two-opt heuristic improvement
```

[image: TSP after two opt improvement]